# Why don't I read voltage on a disconnected heating circuit?

Tags: electric-heat, multimeter

I am trying to replace a broken in-wall electric heater. I wanted to confirm if the heater voltage that I am purchasing is the right one, so I got a multimeter and set it at 200V/500V (AC (V with squiggly line)) and touched the white and black, but there seems to be no voltage between any of the wires (with all the circuit breaker switches ON).

1. Is my multimeter setting wrong (It is set at 200V/500V (AC))
2. How do I know if there's any point where the current is not flowing?
3. I have the same problem with the thermostat which is connected to this heater

[image]

Comment: In most parts of the world, the expected voltage on an in-wall electric heater exceeds 200Volts. 220-250VAC are more typical. In the US 240 would be expected, and if for some reason it was 120 that would still show up on the 500V scale.

Comment: I checked with 500V setting too. (This is in US)

Comment: The old heater was 240V, but the circuit breaker is a single switch (which I think, indicates 120V), that's why I thought the circuit might be a 120V. But I tried with both 200 and 500V setting

Comment: Pedantic clarification: "Voltage present' and "current flowing" are two different things. The only current flowing here would be the tiny amount that your meter draws.

Comment: Picture of the circuit breaker panel would help disambiguate this. *One handle* but *twice as wide* as other one-handle breakers is still 240 V - a 240V resistance heater running on 120V will work, but at 1/4 power. If it has a fan that usually won't work.

Comment: Are you sure you have the multimeter leads in the right holes? A photo of the multimeter showing the setting dial and the plugged in ends of the leads may help.

Comment: OP set the thermostat to 90 degrees (or whatever the max it goes to), otherwise it will not call for heat and you'll see no power.  (yet one of the wires may still be hot). The two bared wires surely must be correct. There are no other wires in sight aside from that one in the back which is green and bare, definitely safety ground which is not a player.

Comment: I will upload the photos and test with the thermostat too shortly. Thank you all. :)

Comment: the thermostat may be bad ... bypass it temporarily and then measure the voltage at the heater

Comment: That's not pedantic, that's the problem. This is the real world, not EE; use a *solenoid voltage tester*. [They're $70](https://www.grainger.com/product/3T887?gclid=CjwKCAiA7939BRBMEiwA-hX5JyG7F5PxEVMesgnJTRNxkpxfxgpBLnEsgzLYUsxttkqzr-WmkmJoBRoC8gMQAvD_BwE&cm_mmc=PPC:+Google+PLA&ef_id=CjwKCAiA7939BRBMEiwA-hX5JyG7F5PxEVMesgnJTRNxkpxfxgpBLnEsgzLYUsxttkqzr-WmkmJoBRoC8gMQAvD_BwE:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!2966!3!264955916564!!!g!442140938772!&gucid=N:N:PS:Paid:GGL:CSM-2295:4P7A1P:20501231), but they're also why I'm still alive.

Comment: So this looks like an epic fail. I got an electrician to come over and he tested the voltage in the heater, in the thermostat, found no activity, no problems in the circuit breaker. Therefore he concluded that the circuit is cut somewhere in the wall